# Applying position relative for a position absolute element.(with respect to child div)

Tags: html, css, position

I want the `div2` to be `relative` to `div3` but since it is already positioned `absolute` to `div1`(relative), I don't know how to achieve that.

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: div2 is the parent of div3 so how you want it to be relative to it (even if we imagine the case there is no aboluste on it)

Comment: I also guess that you approach the bigger issue/plan wrongly. Can you give a more reproduciable sample of what you trying to achieve ultimatly?

Answer (score 0):

If as I understand what you want is to position div3 relatively to div2 you can still do it as an absolute positioned element will refer to a parent with absolute position.

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the
> nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
> viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned
> ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page
> scrolling.
>
> Note: A "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except
> static.

I included a snippet to visualize it.

```css
.div1{
height:150px;
border:1px solid black;
position:relative;
}
.div2{
height:80px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
.div3{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid red;
}
div{
width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```